# How to get data type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In javascript:

```js
var a = 10;
console.log(typeof a); // It's return data type 'Number'
```

How to get data type in Kotlin?

```
var a:Int = 10
println(/* What is the code? */)
```

I just started learning Kotlin.
I searched the document but could not find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the class of a variable like this

```
var a : Int = 10
println(a::class.simpleName) // Int
// or
println(a::class.qualifiedName) // kotlin.Int
```

Answer (score 1):

Print as a string like this

```
println("${a::class.simpleName}")    // "Int"
println("${a::class.qualifiedName}") // "kotlin.Int"
```